# Errors with Opensea bulkTransfer function

Tags: python, web3py, contract, opensea

I want to transfer 2 NFTs in one transaction to 1 address.
I found this function (bulkTransfer) https://arbiscan.io/address/0x0000000000c2d145a2526bD8C716263bFeBe1A72#writeContract and try to use it.

**This is part of my code:**

```
contract_address = w3.to_checksum_address(value=contract)
receiver_address = w3.to_checksum_address(value='0x47a33aB87C8f97Da779576D7862F8A69399d7716')
tx_data = [[(2, w3.to_checksum_address(value=contract_address), 731, 1), (2, w3.to_checksum_address(value=contract_address), 732, 1)], receiver_address, True]
metadata = b'0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000'  # bytes32 value

function = bulk_contract.functions.bulkTransfer(tx_data, metadata)
```

**But the error appears:**

> web3.exceptions.Web3ValidationError:
> Could not identify the intended function with name `bulkTransfer`, positional arguments with type(s) `(((int,address,int,int),(int,address,int,int)),address,bool),bytes` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
> Found 1 function(s) with the name `bulkTransfer`: >  ['bulkTransfer(((uint8,address,uint256,uint256)[],address,bool)[],bytes32)']
> Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.